# preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Compilation failed: unmatched parentheses at offset 8

Tags: php, regex

Why we are getting above error. When we run below code inside a for loop which is running more than 500.

```php
$text22 = preg_replace('/\S*\b('. $searchphrase[$rr] .')\b\S*/i', '<b><a href='.$bbb.' data-color='.$colors1[$clx].','.$colors2[$clx].','.$colors3[$clx].'>$1</a></b>', $aaa);
```

Comment: What does `$searchphrase[$rr]` look like?

Comment: @mazedlx $searchphrase[$rr] is a word which is searching in a string $aaa

Comment: Is it possbile that `$searchpharse[$rr]`contains brackets?

Comment: its a variable not the word.

Comment: No, what I meant was: what's inside `$searchphrase[$rr]`? Is it a string, an integer...? Could it contain brackets?

Comment: it can be any things, may be string or integer

Comment: my code is running perfect for small for loop, but when for loop exceeds from 500 then this error comes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141417/discussion-between-harinarayan-and-mazedlx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that the dynamic string you are placing into your regex contains characters that are special to regular expressions.  An open parenthesis in the string would cause the "unmatched parentheses" error, and "at offset 8" is the second hint the issue is here. You should wrap regex variables in [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php):

```
'/\S*\b('. preg_quote($searchphrase[$rr]) .')\b\S*/i'
```

Comment: can you please suggest me solution for one more query, why sometime print data-color in output from this $text22 = preg_replace('/\S*\b('. preg_quote($searchphrase[$rr]) .')\b\S*/i', '<b><a href='.$bbb.' data-color='.$colors1[$clx].','.$colors2[$clx].','.$colors3[$clx].'>$1</a></b>', $aaa); like data-color=75,0,130>

Comment: I would need a more complete set of code and example data to help debug.  I suggest stepping through your code with a debugger.  Open another SO question if you're still stuck and include more code.

Comment: here I asked this query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43388632/why-we-getting-data-color-and-some-words-repeated-from-the-output-of-preg-replac